# Passing servlet values into <div>

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

on my `Java Servlet` I have something like this,

```
request.setAttribute("InfoLog", info);
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("gc.jsp");
```

and on my `jsp page` I have a `<div>`

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

Now using `Javascript` I want to get the servlet values `InfoLog` and populate that into my div tag, the purpose of this is that I am verifying some conditions in my Javascript function.

How do I get servlet values in `Javascript`?

Comment: All the code in a JSP is executed prior to it being sent to a web browser. If you want to verify user input on the browser side, you will need to read up on AJAX (or AJAH same idea).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the jsp, you get the value from Servlet as below,

```
    <% String infoLog = (String)request.getAttribute("InfoLog"); %>
```

and use this infoLog variable in the div as

```
    <div id="box"><%=infoLog%></div>
```

and in the javascript function particulary in that if condition you can have below code

```
    if(val == "InfoLog")
{
    var infoLog = '<%=infoLog%>';

}
```

Thanks,
Balaji

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get your attribute in your `gc.jsp`

```
<div id="box"> <%=request.getAttribute("InfoLog")%> </div>
```

Then, if you want to get this value in javascript you can write -

```
var val = document.getElementById("box").innerHTML;
```

Comment: I must get the attribute in `Javascript` as I am verifying which option has been selected in my dropdown box using java script